# Evaluation of an Regression Model with r²

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, regression

Using a Bag of Words Model I count the occurences of words per Document (which are Posts from Boards) and create the vector for every Post. Example:

```
X = [[0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0]
     [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
     [1,0,1,0,2,0,0,0]]

y = [22,35,87]
```

In y are the labels/targets to every vector in X (y = the ages of an author).

After training a Regression Model(Linear Regression, Logistic Regression, ...) I use MAE (Mean Absolute Error)
which compares the predicted age with the true age and I get satisfying results.

However i dont quite understand how to use r²:

**Input**

Is it correct that I have to use Predicted labels and the true Labels
(In my case using ages between 14-65)

```
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Isnt that what MAE is for?

**Low r²**

In this Example the predictions are pretty alright:

```
y_predicted = [49, 30, 31, 46, 28, 30]
y_true =      [46, 28, 30, 49, 30, 57]
```

All but one prediction are close to the true age.
MAE is 6.3 years, but scikit-learns r²scorer shows -0.008

Why is it so bad? Just because of one wrong prediction?

**Pearson r**

Also, there is Pearson Correlation "r": 
Does Pearson r squared equals r²?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of determination R² describes the proportion of variance of the dependent variable explained by the regression model. MAE just gives the mean error over all test data. So they are two different ways to measure the performance of a model because each one has it own pitfalls.

R-squared does not indicate whether a regression model is adequate. You can have a low R-squared value for a good model, or a high R-squared value for a model that does not fit the data.

Another fishy thing is, that your value is lower than 0 because normally the output is between 0 and 1, depending on its implementation.

Maybe you could implement the function by yourself, its a very easy one (e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination))

Yes, you should use the predicted labels and the real ones of the tested data.